# symfony2 form entity add values

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, entity

I just need to add other defaults options to an "entity field" in Symfony2. It displays names, and I need an option "Name not in list", but I cant find a way to achieve it. Data transformers cant seem to fix my problem though.

```
$builder
      ->add('family', 'entity', array(
            'class'     => 'InterneFichierBundle:Family',
            'property'  => 'Name'
        ))
```

If the name of the family is not in the list, there should be an option "name not in list"..
Thanks a lot !

Comment: did you have some code to explain it better ?

Comment: just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure you can just specify an empty value option:

```
$builder
  ->add('family', 'entity', array(
        'class'     => 'InterneFichierBundle:Family',
        'property'  => 'Name',
        'empty_value' => 'Name not in list',
    ))
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-value

Comment: Yes, I could use an empty value, but I can only use one, is there any generic solution to add more options ?

Comment: you'd basically need to drop down a level from then entity type to the choice field type.  You'd need to build your choices array yourself and then used a data transformer to have certain values stay as null.
Your other option is to add in your options as rows in your db and use a flag of some sort to show that they are not "real" options, and then  handle the changes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You shouk try with :

for information you can see it here : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

```
    $builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
      'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
         return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
             ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
       },
     ));
```